# How to get a variable from Python file using IronPython

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I want to get a variable from my Python file and write it in the console
here is what i have tried:

## `main.py`

```py
myVar = "Hello There"
```

## `program.cs`

```cs
using System;
using IronPython.Hosting;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var py = Python.CreateEngine();

            var pythonVariable = py.ExecuteFile("main.py");
            Console.WriteLine(pythonVariable);

            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the output to be 'Hello There' but I get this: 'Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope'

Comment: Should you be printing the variable in the `main.py`? There is no output from that script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you get is hinting what you have to look for. `ExecuteFile` returns a `ScriptScope` which contains all the variables defined in the executed Python code.

In order to retrieve a specific variable from it you need to use `GetVariable` or `TryGetVariable` (if the variable may not exist in the file), e.g.:

```
using System;
using IronPython.Hosting;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var py = Python.CreateEngine();

            var pythonVariable = py.ExecuteFile("main.py").GetVariable<string>("myVar");
            Console.WriteLine(pythonVariable);

            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Note that I used the generic version of `GetVariable` to convert it to a `string` immediately. The non-generic version returns a `dynamic` object, choosing which one you need depends on how you intend to use the variable

Answer (score 0):

Follow this procedure and it should work, Be sure to have file in the right place. I don't see you setting any variables Do that and just follow the code:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine(); // Extract Python language engine from their grasp
            var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "myPython.py"));
            var scope = engine.CreateScope();
            source.Execute(scope);
            var theVar = scope.GetVariable("myVar");

            Console.WriteLine(theVar);
            Console.ReadKey();
```